# Get connection using SessionFactory in ASP.NET MVC 4 NHibernate application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, orm

I have created my ASP.NET MVC 4 application with `NHibernate.dll` (version **1.2.0.4000**).

The code before I used is as follow for getting `SqlConnection`:

```
SqlConnection connection = m_SessionFactory.ConnectionProvider.GetConnection() as SqlConnection;
```

After I updated my `NHibernate` version to **3.3.1.4000** now facing error:

> 'NHibernate.ISessionFactory' does not contain a definition for 'ConnectionProvider' and no extension method 'ConnectionProvider' accepting a first argument of type 'NHibernate.ISessionFactory' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please suggest an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case, that you really need that, you can cast your  `ISessionFactory` to its NHibernate implementation:

```
var factory = m_SessionFactory as NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl;
var connection = factory.ConnectionProvider.GetConnection() as SqlConnection;
```

Comment: Great to see that ;) Enjoy NHibernate, amazing tool ;)